Interchanging infinite sum and limit in distribution
I'm trying to do a proof for a project and I've run into the following problem.
For each $j$ consider a sequence $(Y_{j,n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of random variables such that the different sequences are all independent. Assume that
$$X_n := \sum_{j=1}^\infty Y_{j,n}$$
for all $n$ and that the convergence is in $L^2$. If I know that $(X_n)$ has a limit in distribution and that for each $j$, $Y_{j,n}\xrightarrow{\sim} N(0,\sigma_j^2)$ for some $\sigma_j^2 >0$ and such that
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \sigma_j^2 =1,$$
can I then conclude that
$$X_n \xrightarrow{\sim}N(0,1)?$$
If not, what would be a sufficient condition for this to hold?
In this post Weak convergence for infinite sum of random variables they provide an example than in general you cannot interchange summation and convergence in distribution, but I was hoping that I have enough structure for it to work.
